# Calculating temperature change of helium due to Joule-Thomson effect

Tags: thermodynamics

We are trying to fill a rocket helium tank that is 78 liters with helium, final pressure of $\pu{10500 psi}$. We plan to pressurize high pressure tanks to $\pu{20000 psi}$ using a compressing pump system, so that on launch day we don't have to wait for the 78 liter tank to fill slowly by the compressing system. We plan to fill the rocket tanks from the high pressure tanks in a cascade manner (the number and volume of the tanks may vary, depending on the solution of the JT equation(s).

The problem is that helium has a negative JT coefficient. It will heat up during the transfer from the high pressure tanks to the lower pressure tank if I understand it correctly.

So, the concern is how hot will it get. Will the O-rings/seals melt? I have some equations, but it seems to me there may be too many unknowns.

I've seen others make certain assumptions on this site, but its not clear to me how that works. Can anyone advise how you would proceed?

Comment: Can we please focus on a typical single tank transfer as an example.  Tank volumes, pressures before transfer, etc?

Comment: Good question. I'll have to give more details tomorrow after I get to my desk and determine what tank volume is. Pressure before is 20,000,desired final  pressure in the 78 liter receiver is 10,500. The supply tank size may vary, I'll provide an update tomorrow.

Comment: So, now that I'm back at my desk it's all coming back to me. The design so far is to use four high pressure storage tanks pressurized to 20,000 psi. Open one to fill the rocket tank as much as it can towards the 10,500 psi GHe. Then close that valve and open the next one, and cascade until the desired pressure is reached.

Comment: The 78 liters converts to 4730 cu. in. for the rocket tank. The pressure vessels are 890 cu. in.  P3=(P1*V1+P2*V2)/(V1+V2)

Comment: So initially with P1 @ 20,000psi, V1 at 890 cu. in and the rocket tank at 14.7 psi and 4760 cu. in. the settling pressure is 3162 psi. On the next tank we get to 7,108 psi. The third tank gets us to 10,130 psi. The fourth tank could get us all the way to 12,443 psi, but we'd stop when we reach the desired pressure.  The question is, how to calculate the heat gain due to the helium transfer?

Comment: I still don't follow what you are trying to do.  Here is my understanding:  You start out with an 890 cu in tank at 20000 psi.  You then use it to fill a tank initially at 14.7 psi to a pressure 4760 cu in to 3162 psi.  After that, I'm lost.  Have you found an enthalpy-pressure diagram for helium that you can use?

Comment: I see that the formatting allows a way to place an image on here but the instructions aren't clear, does the image have to be hosted on another site with a link or can it be included directly in the comment?

Comment: @ChesterMiller I appreciate your interest. Try sketching 4 pressure holding tanks side by side. Put an valve on each tanks input and out put. Connect the output of each tank to a manifold that connects them to the rocket ship tank. Fill each of the 4 tanks individually to 20,000 psi, one at a time. Close all inlet valves. Open Tank 1 outlet valve to the rocket, wait for the tank to fill to the settling pressure. Close Tank 1 outlet valve.

Comment: Open tank 2 outlet valve to the rocket, wait for the tank to fill to the settling pressure. Close Tank 2 outlet valve. Open tank 3 outlet valve to the rocket, wait for the tank to fill to the settling pressure. Close Tank 3 outlet valve. Open tank 4 outlet valve to the rocket, wait for the tank to fill to the settling pressure, or until we reach launch pressure. I hope that is clear enough. Now, Helium has a negative JT constant, it heats up when it goes from a high pressure (20,000 psi) to a lower pressure. How much heat does the helium gain at each valve opening to the rocket tank?

Comment: I was unable to fine an enthalpy-pressure diagram for helium. I did find an Enthalpy Entropy Chart for helium on page II-F-2 on the PDF at https://www.bnl.gov/magnets/staff/gupta/cryogenic-data-handbook/Section2.pdf that has lines for pressure and temperature, would that be useful?

Comment: The pressures don't go high enough in the charts.  And I get the picture of what the system is.  One final question:  the "settling" pressure:  this is the pressure at which you shut the valve, or is it the pressure at which the two tanks equilibrate in pressure?

Comment: The worst case scenario is when the helium is going through the valve from 20000 psi in the first tank to 14.7 psi (just as the rocket tank begins to fill), right?

Comment: I would agree that the worst case temperature increase would be going from the highest pressure to the lowest.  The "settling pressure" is what I think is where equilibrium occurs by using the P3=(P1*V1+P2*V2)/(V1+V2) calculation, it is theoretical.

Comment: In any event, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

To do this analysis, one needs data up to 20000 psi (1400 bars) on either enthalpy vs temperature and pressure (a graph) or compressibility factor Z vs temperature and pressure.  The only graphs I have found of the former type go up to only 100 bars, which is a factor of 14 too low.  However, I have found data on the compressibility factor Z at temperatures up to 300 K and pressures up to 1000 bars:  https://cds.cern.ch/record/1444601/files/978-1-4419-9979-5_BookBackMatter.pdf
Although this is still a factor of 1.4 too low, it might provide some idea of the temperature rise that might be expected in the valve.

So here is how the data would be used.

The effect of pressure on enthalpy (per mole) of gas is given by $$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T=V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\tag{1}$$For a real gas, the equation of state in terms of the compressibility factor Z=Z(P,T) is given by$$PV=ZRT\tag{2}$$If we substitute Eqn. 2 into Eqn. 1, we obtain:  $$\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial P}\right)_T=-\frac{RT^2}{P}\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}\right)_P\tag{3}$$Integrating Eqn. 3 between P=0 and arbitrary P at constant temperature yields the so-called Residual Enthalpy $H^R$:$$H^R(P,T)=-RT^2\int_0^P{\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}\right)_{P'}\frac{dP'}{P'}}=-RT^2\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\int_0^P{(Z(T,P')-1)\frac{dP'}{P'}}\right)\tag{4}$$where P' is a dummy variable of integration.

If the final pressure coming out of the valve is low (so that the gas exiting the valve is in the ideal gas region), we can write:  $$\Delta H=-H^R+C_p\Delta T=0$$where, for a monoatomic gas like Helium, $C_p=\frac{5}{2}R$.  Therefore, $$\Delta T=-\frac{2}{5}T^2\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\int_0^P{(Z(T,P')-1)\frac{dP'}{P'}}\right)\tag{5}$$
This expression would be evaluated using the data presented in the reference above.

If a reference can be found with data going out to 1400 bar, that would be even better.

Comment: Thank you @Chester Miller for your effort in putting all this together. If I understand this correctly, I would have to integrate the equation inside the parenthesis, take the derivative of that over ∂T, then multiply that by -2/5T squared, is that what you are telling me?

Comment: Yes.  You would use the data in the reference, and integrate numerically with respect to lnP, and differentiate numerically with respect to T.  You would also be extrapolating to fill in the blank between 1000 bars  and 1400 bars.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the Joule Thomson heating or cooling there are basically two approaches.

When considering a small pressure change, the temperature change can be approximated by multiplying the JT coefficient at the outlet conditions by the pressure change. The issue with this is that on beforehand you don't know what the outlet temperature is, so you need to assume the same as the inlet, which causes errors, as the JT coefficient is temperature dependent.

The better approach is to use a TP diagram with isenthalps. This can be used to accurately determine the final temperature. It is based on the fact that the expansion is isenthalpic, i.e. the enthalpy doesn't change. Hence, you plot your initial condition in the PT diagram, then follow (parallel to) the isenthalp to your final pressure, and simply read the final temperature from the diagram. You can use this approach with an actual diagram, or you could use a computer program, which would perform the underlying calculations for you. In that case you would need to perform a two-step calculation:

1. At the initial conditions (T1, P1) you calculate the enthalpy H
2. Use the final pressure (P2) and the calculated enthalpy to calculate the final temperature T2

Many software programs exist that can perform these calculations, such as [NIST Refprop](https://www.nist.gov/srd/refprop).

Alternatively, you could manually perform the above calculations using a simpler Equation of state, such as Peng-Robinson, for which you only need to know the following parameters of Helium for the calculation:

1. Critical temperature (5.19 K)
2. Critical pressure (227400 Pa)
3. Acentric factor (- 0.36)
4. Ideal gas Heat capacity (20.78603 J/molK)

This will be somewhat less accurate, and a lot more work, than the use of dedicated software. Fortunately you're looking at Helium, which is just about the most well behaved gas there is, so the inaccuracies using a simple Equation of state are likely to be fairly small.